# nVidia updated driver issue. Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia

Same issue as most other people, can't boot after upgrading graphics drivers. All I get is a flashing cursor in top left. Can't switch tty with alt+f1/f2 etc or ctrl+alt+f1/f2 etc can't get grub to load with holding shiftkey on boot. Completely lost. Ubuntu 13.10.

I know what to do IF I get to the prompt or terminal. But I can't even get there.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Can be loaded in text mode.

Press 'e' to edit

[image: 'e' to edit]

Add in the right place 'nomodeset' and CTRL+X

[image: write 'nomodeset' and CTRL+X]

P.S. images for example

Comment: "can't get grub to load with holding shiftkey on boot."